# Getting the first character of a word taken from user input using Scanner

Tags: java, substring, java.util.scanner

I want to use a `Scanner` to get a word from the user, then print the first character of that word. For example, for the word `"Lucas"`, it will print out `'L'`.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IDname {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String first;
        String second;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        first = scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

What code should I add after this line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `subString(0, 1);` Where the first argument is the startIndex inclusive and the second is endIndex exclusive. More info at [substring tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/substring).

```
public static void main (String[]args){
  String first;
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
  first = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.println("your name =" + first);
  if (first.length() > 0) {
        System.out.printf("The first character of your name = %s\n", first.substring(0, 1));
  }

}
```